# Mocha Testing authenticated APIs provided by a server

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, passport.js, supertest

My APIs can be used after logging in. For example, `/api/sales` requires an authentication like below code. (I'm using Node.js and Express.js)

```
app.all('/api/*', userController.requiresLogin);
app.route('/api/sales')
    .get(common.readAll(Sale, 'name'))
    .post(common.create(Sale));
```

The `userController.requiresLogin` function is:

```
exports.requiresLogin = function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('Check login...');

    if(!req.user) return res.status(401).send();
    else next();
};
```

To login, I use `passport.js`.

```
exports.login = passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    failureFlash: false
});
```

When I run my server and test this API on my browser, it works.

To test this API automatically, I built my Mocha test code using Supertest.

```
    var request = require('supertest'),
        should = require('should'),
        utils = require('./../utils'),
        mongoose = require('mongoose');

    var Sale = mongoose.model('Sale'),
        User = mongoose.model('User');

    var user;

    describe('Controller Testing:', function() {
        describe('Sale Controller Testing:', function() {
            var agent = request.agent();

            beforeEach(function(done) {
                user = new User({
                    username:'defaultUser@test.com',
                    password: 1234,
                    userId: 'default user'
                });
                user.save();

                request(app).post('/login')
                    .send( {username: 'defaultUser@test.com', password: '1234'} )
                    .end(function(err, res) {
                        should.not.exist(err);
                        agent.saveCookies(res);
                        done();
                    });
            });

            afterEach(function() {
                User.remove({}, function(){});
                Sale.remove({}, function(){});
            }

            it('create a sale', function(done) {
                var sale = {
                    name: 'New Sale',
                    orders: [order1]
                };

                var req = request(app).post('/api/sales')
                    .send(sale)
                    .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
                    .expect(200);
                agent.attachCookies(req);

                req.end(function(err, res) {
                    console.log(res.statusCode);

                    res.body.name.should.equal('New Sale');
                    done();
                });
            });
    }
```

**This test keeps failed**. The test 'create a sale' cannot identify that a user has logged in, even though I saved and attached corresponding cookies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [supertest npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest), and revise your test script as

```
   var request = require('supertest'),
    should = require('should'),
    utils = require('./../utils'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Sale = mongoose.model('Sale'),
    User = mongoose.model('User');

var user;

describe('Controller Testing:', function() {
    describe('Sale Controller Testing:', function() {
        var agent = request.agent(app); // revised

        beforeEach(function(done) {
            user = new User({
                username:'defaultUser@test.com',
                password: 1234,
                userId: 'default user'
            });
            user.save();

            agent.post('/login') // revised
                .send( {username: 'defaultUser@test.com', password: '1234'} )
                .expect("set-cookie", "check correct cookie here") // appended
                .end(function(err, res) {
                    should.not.exist(err);
                    //agent.saveCookies(res);
                    // or write some code to check your cookie here
                    done();
                });
        });

        afterEach(function() {
            User.remove({}, function(){});
            Sale.remove({}, function(){});
        }

        it('create a sale', function(done) {
            var sale = {
                name: 'New Sale',
                orders: [order1]
            };

            var req = agent.post('/api/sales') // revised
                .send(sale)
                .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
                .expect(200);
            //agent.attachCookies(req);

            req.end(function(err, res) {
                console.log(res.statusCode);

                res.body.name.should.equal('New Sale');
                done();
            });
        });
}
```

I didn't see where is `app` come from in your test script, assume you got it correctly and applied `cookieParser` middleware.

I think the problem in your test script is **request just sent before cookie attached**. Maybe you can also try

```
var req = aggent.attachCookies(request(app));
req.post('/api/sales')
     .send(sale)
     .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
     .expect(200);
     //agent.attachCookies(req);
```

Comment: Your revision works! Thanks! The problem seems that my original code keeps making separate `request(app)` rather than using same `agent`.